# How to get a variable from cmd and show it in vbscript - Vbscript

Tags: vba, vbscript, adsutil.vbs

i'm a beginner of vbscript , i need you help , my question is how do i do to get a variable from cmd and show it in vbscript for example get a ping from www.google.com and show it in a msgbox in vbscript help me code :

`dim cmd,x
set cmd = createobject("wscript.shell")
x= cmd.run("cmd /k ping www.google.com ",1,true)`

Get that output and show it in a msgbox later , help me

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how to do that.
The response of the ping that is checked is in Dutch but that doesn't matter for your case.

```
Set objExec = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("ping www.google.com")

With objExec 
  Do While .Status = 0 
    WScript.Sleep 10 
    Do While Not .StdOut.AtEndOfStream 
      WScript.Echo .StdOut.ReadLine
      'Check the .StdErr to see if it is at the end of its
      'stream. If not, call ReadLine on it
      If Not .StdErr.AtEndOfStream Then
         .StdErr.ReadLine
      End If
    Loop
  Loop 
End With
```

An advise though, don't begin scripting in vbscript, it's a dead end.
Choose some modern scripting language like Python or still better for beginners: Ruby.

Be sure to use cscript as engine in stead of wscript, execute the following to set that as default.

```
wscript //H:Cscript
```

Your vbscript is then one single line

```
puts `ping www.google.com`
```

Comment: I suppose you mean the vbscript code ? I published a simplified version that should run (the original is for a Dutch version of windows)
For the Ruby code you need to install Ruby first https://rubyinstaller.org/