# Calling powershell script in VBA with return value

Tags: vba, powershell

Let's say I have a powershell script sorta like this:

```
'Hey'
```

Which I want to call in VBA sorta like this:

```
Sub CallPowerShell()

    Call Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Users\chm\Documents\5.ps1")

End Sub
```

I know this works as a console window briefly pops up with the word 'Hey' in it. What I really want however, is to use this string in my VBA code.

Is there a simple way how to get a return value from a powershell script through VBA?

Ideally it would be something like this:

```
Dim x As String

Sub CallPowerShell()

    x = Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Users\chm\Documents\5.ps1")

End Sub
```

But that just sets x to seemingly random numbers like 70640 or 30960.

I could have the powershell script write the value I want to a file and then read the file in VBA but it'd be really nice if I could skip that so I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a variable from cmd and show it in vbscript - Vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845763/how-to-get-a-variable-from-cmd-and-show-it-in-vbscript-vbscript)

Comment: There are many answers that show you how to use the `WScript.Shell` object from VBA (or VBS, does not make much difference). Look at a few of them.